# Send data stream over bluetooth [from linux pc to android phone]

Tags: linux, android, yocto-project

I'm working on a project where data needs to be sent over bluetooth (from Yocto linux development board (or EVK) to android phone).

(Board running on linux will not have display) (i'll run a script on boot-up that in turn runs a c program to send byte stream over bluetooth).

My question is :
How to make BT on Yocto linux to work as Broadcaster and on android device i should be able to pair to that board (that does't have a display) and get byte stream.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While this forum sees questions of all types there are more specific forums on StackExchange for Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and for programming https://stackoverflow.com/

This question might get better answers on a more specific site for Yocto Linux or maybe check the forums for the board you are using.

Comment: What is the specific make and model of the development board you are using?